# Running a stored procedure as a job in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a stored procedure in a job, and this is what i have in the command box on the job setup.

EXEC "sp_uss_Hi-Valley_Chemical"

the report is set as TSQL.

it gives me the error incorrect syntax near 'Valley_Chemical'. I just put in " " (quotes) and it is still giving me the same error.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try throwing square brackets around the proc name:

```
EXEC [sp_uss_Hi-Valley_Chemical]
```

Comment: do i need to specify a database? its telling me it cant find the store procedure

Answer (score 1):

The dash is not a valid character for a stored procedure name.  That is why it is throwing the error.  Here is a link to Microsoft's documentation on what is allowed:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: now the error says "Incorrect syntax near 'sp_uss_Hi_Valley_Chemical'

Comment: You would need to be sure that the stored procedure name is correct.  Can you run this in the editor window directly or does it error there too?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the name of the procedure in square brackets.

```
EXEC [sp_uss_Hi-Valley_Chemical]
```

Also, you should not start procedure names with "sp_". See: [Stored Procedure performance using “sp_” prefix – Myth or fact?](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/stored-procedure-performance-using-%E2%80%9Csp_%E2%80%9D-prefix-%E2%80%93-myth-or-fact/)